# Delete an image without reloading a page

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using below function in my page.
I use this function to delete an one or more uploaded images.
The code is working fine,but its reloading a page when i click on "delete" button.
Is it possible to delete an images  without reloading a page using "post" method or ajax?

```
<div onclick="delete_Files_Inmos1('Seguro de Eliminar el Archivo','im_Delete_Chk','im_FileUp','im_imgF','<?php echo $url?>',<?php echo $this->config->maxFileUpload?>,<?php echo $count?>);">delete</div>
<script>
    function delete_Files_Inmos1(message,varbase,varimginput,varimgg,urlbase,maximg,imgdelete)
    {
        if(confirm(message)){
            var obj;var imgsdelete='';
            obj=AJAX_MM_findObj(varbase+imgdelete);
            if(obj)obj.checked=true;
            for(i=0;i<maximg;i++){
                obj=AJAX_MM_findObj(varbase+i);
                if(obj){
                    if(obj.checked==true){
                        obj=AJAX_MM_findObj(varimginput+i);
                        if(imgsdelete!='')imgsdelete=imgsdelete+'[,]';
                        imgsdelete=imgsdelete+obj.value;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.location=urlbase+'&'+varimgg+'='+imgsdelete;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return `false` in your `onClick` function!

Comment: I tried but its not working still its reloading a page

Comment: @user3350169 you have `onClick='delete_Files_Inmos1()'` in your **HTML** and `delete_Files_Inmos()` in **Javascript**, those are two different methods

Comment: By mistake i have written like that ,but in my page i have written same function name

Comment: ya its showing error like :"Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable' " for select menu

Comment: @user3350169 `document.location=urlbase+'&'+varimgg+'='+imgsdelete;` this will redirect page to `urlbase+'&'+varimgg+'='+imgsdelete;` generated URL, if u want to send request to another location so that page wont reload u can use **ajax** to send it

Comment: I am new to ajax will you tell me please how to use it.I checked in others question but i didn't get how to use in my code

Comment: simple as that:
`xmlhttp.open("GET","example.com/file/path?key1=value1&key2=value2",true);`
`xmlhttp.send();`
First parameter is what method to use for **http request**, second **URL** where to send request and file path to **php** file or whatever file is handling the request, and third one is if request should be asynchronous or not. In **php** u can get those values that u pass from `$_GET[]` array.

Comment: Happy to hear that can you check this as an answer please:))